# what should I use instead of document.write for a popup

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

in my web page, I am opening a popup window and generate the HTML for the popup using JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var site="<html> ............. </html>";
var popupWindow = window.open("","","menubar=0,scrollbars=0");
popupWindow.document.write(site);
```

The problem is, that the popup window shows "reading" in the status bar. What should I use instead of document.write()?

EDIT:

```
document.close();
```

should do the work, thanks. Unfortunately, my framework may be interfering, so it's not working for me in FF. IE works.

Comment: I dont know if you want a new window or not, because you could perhaps just use a div with an overly etc (that you cant drag or anything).

Comment: I personally wouldn't worry about this too much. If your popup shows data from a slow process you might show some sort of loading bar or progress indicator while it loads.

Comment: It loads fast, it's a small HTML code. But still, I don't want the page to be loading. Is there an alternative to document.write for writing a whole page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to close the document when you'r done writing:

```
var site="<html> ............. </html>";
var popupWindow = window.open("","","menubar=0,scrollbars=0");
popupWindow.document.write(site);
popupWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: You should have document.open() before the write(). MDN doc for [document.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.close)

Comment: @epascarello also from MDN: _Also, an automatic document.open() call happens when document.write() is called after the page has loaded, but that's not defined in the W3C specification. document non-spec'ed parameters to document.open_

Comment: Thanks for this answers. Now I use open, write, close, but it still does not work on the server. It works only locally on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

```
popupWindow.document.close();
```

Adding this to the end will solve the issue.
I have found it here before : http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript-how/36703-javascript-popup-keeps-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery's `append()`

```
var win = window.open();
    var popup = win.document.body;
    $(popup).append('site html');
```

Or `innerHTML`

```
var popup = window.open();
popup.document.body.innerHTML = 'site data here';
```