# Open link in Popup Window with Javascript but pop up should be in new window

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to send a popup window of specific dimensions which also centers in the screen.

Here is my source:

```
 <li>
   <a class="google" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 545, 433)">Test</a>
 </li>
```

And JAVASCRIPT IS:

```
function windowpop(url, width, height) {

    alert('hello');

    var leftPosition, topPosition;

    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);

    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);

    //Open the window.
    window.open(url, "Window2", "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + 
    ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + 
    leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + 
    ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no");
}
```

In this the pop up is generated. But I need that alert message in new window.

Comment: Not able to put the html code their. So that HTML code is:
{ <li>
<a class="google" 
href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 545, 433)">Test</a>
            </li>}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646800/what-should-i-use-instead-of-document-write-for-a-popup

Comment: you need to write that `alert' in the new opened window code

Comment: Thanks foeroz. But using this I am not able to intimate that user.

Answer (score 2):

> But I need that alert message in new window.

Since you are opening the ***same*** page (`this.href`), before *calling* the `alert` function, check if the current window has a parent (i.e. if it is a pop-up window):

```
    if (window.opener) {
    {
      alert('hello');
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

You should extract out the `alert('hello');` code from the `windowpop` function and put it directly in the `<script>` section so that the opened page will load it.

Like that:

```
    <script>
    if (window.opener) {
    {
      alert('hello');
      ...
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Yair. Now checking that.

Comment: Same issue is their. Pop up comes before opening that window.

Comment: Actually I am trying to send that pop up to the specific user in my network. But for testing purpose trying to create on new window. Help me out in this situation.

Comment: this.href bec I am sending this from some other page. And using this.href trying to send a message on that specific location i.e. google.com

Comment: You can't manipulate external pages and embed an `alert within` them!

Comment: Ok. Means Its not possible with java script to send a message through pop up to any specific url. If such a condition then which language or script should I follow.

Comment: @RajeevKumarSrivastava It is a security breach, I don't think that you will be able to achieve it in any modern web-browser.

Comment: Thanks for providing me valuable thinks.

Comment: But If I will create something9 in my own domain and trying to fill the form from one user then will it possible to send that message to next user in same domain.

Comment: @RajeevKumarSrivastava The rule is simple, do what ever you want in your resources (HTML).