# append image javascript occasionally fails

Tags: javascript

I am using the below script to format a special print window from my sharepoint site.

The problem is sometimes the very last statement in the script (the picture append) does not load. Is there a way to catch if it fails and force the script to reload ?

I have tried loading the picture directly in the printing html but it seems to not work.

I am not very experienced with javascript, any suggestions of improvement are very welcome

```
<center> 
   <input onclick="PrintWebPart();" type="button" value="Print Proof of Pricing"/>  
</center>
<script language="JavaScript">
//Controls which Web Part or zone to print
var WebPartElementID = "ctl00_ctl34_g_db6615a7_4c3b_4a14_9bbc_43ce9d63c24d_FormControl0";
var d= new Date();


//Function to print Web Part
function PrintWebPart() {
  var bolWebPartFound = false;
  if (document.getElementById != null) {
    //Create html to print in new window
    var PrintingHTML = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';
    //Take data from Head Tag
    if (document.getElementsByTagName != null) {
      var HeadData= document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD");
      if (HeadData.length > 0) {
        PrintingHTML += HeadData[0].innerHTML;
      }
    }
    PrintingHTML += '\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n';
    var WebPartData = document.getElementById(WebPartElementID);
    if (WebPartData != null) {
      PrintingHTML +='<div id="imageDiv" align="center">\n</div>\n'
      PrintingHTML += WebPartData.innerHTML;
      PrintingHTML += "Pricing Date: " +d;
      bolWebPartFound = true;
    } else {
      bolWebPartFound = false;
      alert ('Cannot Find Web Part');
    }
  }
  PrintingHTML += '\n</BODY>\n</HTML>';
  //Open new window to print
  if (bolWebPartFound) {
    var PrintingWindow = window.open("","Print_Proof_of_Pricing", "toolbar= yes,width=800,height=600,scrollbars,resizable,menubar");
    PrintingWindow.document.open();
    PrintingWindow.document.write(PrintingHTML);
    PrintingWindow.document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="Some_url" alt="Title" height="170" width="300"/>';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Which is the "very last statement" may I ask?

Comment: 'PrintingWindow.document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="Some_url" alt="Title" height="170" width="300"/>';'

Comment: Can you try out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646800/what-should-i-use-instead-of-document-write-for-a-popup ? Add a `.close()` before editing the innerHTML?

Comment: on IE it seems to work better now, chrome however no longer displays the picture at all

Comment: Well it works for me every time in FF and Chrome with and without the change.